# how to save parsed json data into an array with swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift3, tableview

So i received some json data from a server now am trying to save it as an array so i can populate a tableview with it but am having a trouble doing it here is my code :

```
class UserInfo : UIViewController{
var main = ""
session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print (response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))
            print(json)
            guard let array = json as? [Any] else {return}
            for info in array {
            guard let infoDict = info as? [String : Any] else{return}
            //there is a declared var called main
            //main is the one i want save as an array, currently its a variable. i tried to save it as an array by using as! Array but i get error
            self.main = infoDict["Title"] as! String
            print (self.main)
}
}
}.resume()
}
```

Comment: So you need to post the json received so we know what data are we dealing with.

Comment: "but i get error" What error?

Comment: you want to store these data in UserDefaults?

Comment: Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x60800004c390>(
{
    Body = 21456;
    InfoID = 159;
    Title = "\U062d\U0633\U0627\U0628 \U0642\U062f\U0648\U0633 \U0641\U064a \U0642\U0648\U0644\U0644\U064a";
    UserID = "db9b9dce-2c4d-413d-be2d-b61d01bbef3b";
    infoType = 3;
}
//thats how it looks like(the received data)

Comment: nope i just want to save them as array so i can view them in a table

Comment: is the question not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to declare `ary` outside of the request scope. Then you have to store your data in the same `ary`.

```
var ary: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print (response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))
                print(json)
                guard let array = json as? [Any] else {return}
                for info in array {
                    guard let infoDict = info as? [String : Any] else{return}
                    //there is a declared var called main
                    //main is the one i want save as an array, currently its a variable. i tried to save it as an array by using as! Array but i get error
                    self.main = infoDict["Title"] as! String
                    self.ary.add(self.main)
                    print (self.main)
                }
                print("Final array is :::",self.ary)
            }
            }.resume()
```

Try above code. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: worked fine but i just added "self" to this "print("Final array is :::",self.ary)"

Comment: @Duck.P Yes, sorry for that. Because it's a closure where we are making a request for getting data from server. Thank you.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
            let cell = UITableViewCell (style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            cell.textLabel?.text = arry 
        //when i do this (cell.textlable?.text = arry) i get error (Cannot assign //value of type 'NSMutableArray' to type 'String?')            
return (cell)
        }

Comment: Yes, compiler will give you a error at run time. Because you are assign value from `NSMutableArray` to `UILabel` setText property. You can't do this. Though If you want to assign value you want compulsory array instead of label.

Like below Code :-

`cell.ary = arry`
`cell.ary` means your NSMutableArray in `UITableViewCell` class instance.
`arry` means your parsed data container.